# Como optimizar un insert en mysql en el servidor online

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente situación: estoy realizando un proceso donde creo una tabla y después inserto los datos en ella. El proceso de creación de la tabla se hace rápido, el problema lo tengo cuando hago el insert en la tabla que acabe de crear. El query que realizo para extraer los datos para el insert lo logre disminuir de 8 a 6 ms. Pero aun así me sigue siendo el proceso muy lento. Si lo ejecuto en mi servidor local que está en mi PC con menos recursos que el servidor que el servidor online se demora 5 seg mientras que en el online 20 seg o más. A continuación les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

```
public function set_tmptable($fecha1, $fecha2, $search, $idpedido)
{
    //Borramos la tabla para volverla a crear.
    $this->db->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_resumen");
    $tbl = "CREATE TABLE `tmp_resumen` (
                  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `id_empl` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                  `referencia` int(15) NOT NULL,
                  `nombre` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
                  ";

    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT `periodo`.`fecha_inicio`,`periodo`.`fecha_final`  FROM `periodo` WHERE `periodo`.`id` = '".$idpedido."'");
    if($q->num_rows > 0){
        $obj = $q->fetch_object();
        $max = strtotime($obj->fecha_final);
        $min = strtotime($obj->fecha_inicio);
        for($i = $min; $i<= $max; $i += 86400){
            $tbl .= "`f" . date("Y_m_d", $i) . "` varchar(5) NOT NULL,";
        }
    }

    $tbl .=  "PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              KEY `id` (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    $this->db->query($tbl);

    unset($per_sql);

    if (isset($fecha1) and isset($fecha2)) {
        $per_sql =  "AND asistencia.fecha_ent >= '" . $fecha1 . "' AND asistencia.fecha_ent <= '" . $fecha2 . "'";
    } elseif (isset($fecha1) or isset($fecha2)) {
        $fecha = ($fecha1) ? $fecha1 : $fecha2;
        $per_sql =  "AND asistencia.fecha_ent = '" . $fecha . "' ";
    }

    //Insertamos los datos en la tabla temporal.
    $qcolum = $this->db->query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tmp_resumen'");

    while ($row_colum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qcolum)) {

        if ($row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'id') {
            $nombre_cor = substr($row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'], 1, 3);
            $qresum =  $this->db->query("SELECT empleado.id_empl, empleado.fecha_baja, `empleado`.`baja`, empleado.referencia, CONCAT(empleado.apellidos,' ',empleado.nombre) AS nombre,tipo_asist.id, tipo_asist.nombre_abe, `asistencia`.`fecha_ent` FROM asistencia INNER JOIN empleado ON asistencia.id_empl = empleado.id_empl INNER JOIN tipo_asist ON asistencia.id_tipoasist = tipo_asist.id WHERE 1  " . $search . "  ORDER BY referencia ASC, fecha_ent ASC ");

            while ($row_resum =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresum)) {

                if ((strtotime($row_resum['fecha_baja']) > strtotime($fecha1)) AND $row_resum['baja'] == 1) {
                    //Comprobamos si existe el usuario en la tabla temporal.
                    $qempl = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM tmp_resumen WHERE referencia = '" . $row_resum['referencia'] . "'");

                    if ($row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'id_empl' and $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'referencia' and $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'nombre') {
                        unset($data);

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($qempl) > 0) {

                            $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($qempl);

                            $campo = $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'];
                            if(substr($campo,1) == str_replace("-","_",$row_resum['fecha_ent'])){
                                $this->db->query("UPDATE tmp_resumen SET ".$campo."='".$row_resum['nombre_abe']."' WHERE id = '".$obj->id."'");
                            }
                            //classDb::update_db('tmp_resumen', $data, array('id' => $obj->id));
                        } else {
                            $campo = $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'];
                            if(substr($campo,1) == str_replace("-","_",$row_resum['fecha_ent'])){
                                $campos = "id_empl,referencia,nombre,".$campo;
                                $value = "'".$row_resum['id_empl']."','".$row_resum['referencia']."','".$row_resum['nombre']."','".$row_resum['nombre_abe']."'";
                                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tmp_resumen (".$campos.") VALUES (".$value.")");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } elseif((strtotime($row_resum['fecha_baja']) < strtotime($fecha1)) AND $row_resum['baja'] != 1) {
                    //Comprobamos si existe el usuario en la tabla temporal.
                    $qempl = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM tmp_resumen WHERE referencia = '" . $row_resum['referencia'] . "'");

                    if ($row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'id_empl' and $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'referencia' and $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'nombre') {
                        unset($data);

                        if (mysqli_num_rows($qempl) > 0) {

                            $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($qempl);

                            $campo = $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'];
                            if(substr($campo,1) == str_replace("-","_",$row_resum['fecha_ent'])){
                                $this->db->query("UPDATE tmp_resumen SET ".$campo."='".$row_resum['nombre_abe']."' WHERE id = '".$obj->id."'");
                            }

                        } else {
                            $campo = $row_colum['COLUMN_NAME'];
                            if(substr($campo,1) == str_replace("-","_",$row_resum['fecha_ent'])){
                                $campos = "id_empl,referencia,nombre,".$campo;
                                $value = "'".$row_resum['id_empl']."','".$row_resum['referencia']."','".$row_resum['nombre']."','".$row_resum['nombre_abe']."'";
                                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tmp_resumen (".$campos.") VALUES (".$value.")");

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: podrías incluir la estructura de tu tabla, un mínimo de data ejemplo, que deseas hacer y el resultado esperado ya que viendo tu código no se puede optimizar las query...puedes ayudarte de la herramienta [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por la respuesta por favor me puede decir que tabla necesita para colocarla

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del ciclo estás ejecutando una consulta para obtener datos por cada columna y, de hecho, los resultados seguramente se repiten en cada iteración, porque no haces filtro por usuario ni fecha.

Además, estás ejecutando una consulta para verificar y después insertar o actualizar cada columna en cada registro de la tabla que acabas de crear.

Con tu lógica actual, podrías crear el filtro por fecha, obteniéndola del nombre de cada columna, pero seguirías con el inconveniente de ejecutar dos consultas por cada columna y cada registro.

Para obtener un mejor rendimiento debes armar y ejecutar una sola consulta para insertar, que incluya todas las columnas. Eliminando el ciclo `while ($row_colum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qcolum)) {` y pasando directamente a obtener los resultados de asistencia:

```
$qresum =  $this->db->query("SELECT empleado.id_empl, empleado.fecha_baja, empleado.baja, empleado.referencia,
    CONCAT(empleado.apellidos,' ',empleado.nombre) AS nombre, tipo_asist.id, tipo_asist.nombre_abe, asistencia.fecha_ent
    FROM asistencia
    INNER JOIN empleado ON asistencia.id_empl = empleado.id_empl
    INNER JOIN tipo_asist ON asistencia.id_tipoasist = tipo_asist.id
    WHERE 1  $search
    ORDER BY referencia ASC, fecha_ent ASC ");

// Saber cuándo crear una nueva consulta
$inertar = '';
$referencia = 0;
while ($row_resum =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresum)) {
    if($row_resum['referencia'] != $referencia) {
        // Es referencia nueva
       if($insertar != '') {
              // No esta vacía, hay que ejecutar
              $this->db->query($insertar);
       }
       $referencia = $row_resum['referencia'];
       // Crear cadena de inserción con los campos que ya se conocen
       $insertar = "INSERT INTO tmp_resumen SET `id` = {$obj->id}, id_empl = {$row_resum['id_empl']}, referencia = $referencia, nombre = '{$row_resum['nombre']}'";
    }
    // En cada iteración solo se agrega de acuerdo a fecha_ent
    // Solo se necesita la fecha para obtener el nombre de la columna
    $columna = 'f' . str_replace("-","_",$row_resum['fecha_ent']);
    $insertar .= ", $columna = '{$row_resum['nombre_abe']}'";
}
// Si $insertar no está vacía, hay una consulta que no se ha ejecutado
// porque quedó abierta al final del ciclo
if($insertar != '') {
    $this->db->query($insertar);
}
```

Por cierto, hay detalles que se deben corregir como:

- `$obj->id` podría no estar definido, porque no es un campo que especifiques en la primera consulta
- Si esa primera consulta no devuelve resultados, en `if($q->num_rows > 0){` debes agregar un `else` para evitar que se siga ejecutando el script
- A los campos creados con `$tbl .= "f" . date("Y_m_d", $i) . " varchar(5) NOT NULL,";` deberías quitar el `NOT NULL` y dejar solo `NULL`, para evitar errores en caso de que alguno quede vacío
- No estás usando la variable `$pers_sql`
- Consumes más recursos de los necesarios por incluir en la consulta columnas que no usas posteriormente